# Вывести значения двух массивов в две колонки

Tags: c#, массивы

Помогите вывести значения двух массивов так ,чтобы было две колонки рядом и первым массив выводился бы меньший по размеру,который вводит пользователь.

```
Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer pervogo massiva: ");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr1 = new int[a];


Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer vtorogo massiva: ");
int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr2 = new int[b];

int min = 10;
int max = 100;
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i <arr1.Length&&i<arr2.Length; i++)
{

    arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
    arr2[i] = rand.Next(min, max);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}     {1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решил сделать так, чтобы `arr1` был заведомо длиннее. Если при вводе получается, что `arr2` длиннее `arr1`, то меняем ссылки на массивы местами. И печатаем более оптимально, без лишнего `if` внутри цикла.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer pervogo massiva: ");
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr1 = new int[a];


    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer vtorogo massiva: ");
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr2 = new int[b];

    int min = 10;
    int max = 100;
    Random rand = new Random();

    // Меняем местами массивы так, чтобы arr1 был больше arr2 по длине
    if (arr1.Length < arr2.Length)
    {
        var tmp = arr1;
        arr1 = arr2;
        arr2 = tmp;
    }

    // Сначала печатаем по 2 элемента, пока не дойдем до конца arr2
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
        arr2[i] = rand.Next(min, max);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}     {1}", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }

    // Допечатываем arr1
    for (int i = arr2.Length; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public void PrintArrays<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> a, ReadOnlySpan<T> b, bool alignToRight)
{
    const string col1Header = "First";
    const string col1Border = "-----"
    const string col2Header = "Second";
    const string col2Border = "------";

    if (a.Length > b.Length)
        Swap(ref a, ref b); // non-std swap method

    using var aStrOwner = MemoryPool<string>.Shared.Rent(a.Length);
    var aStr = aStrOwner.Memory.Span;
    using var bStrOwner = MemoryPool<string>.Shared.Rent(b.Length);
    var bStr = bStrOwner.Memory.Span;

    var aMaxStrLen = 0;
    var bMaxStrLen = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        aStr[i] = a[i]?.ToString() ?? "";

        if (aStr[i].Length > aMaxStrLen)
            aMaxStrLen = aStr[i].Length;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        bStr[i] = b[i]?.ToString() ?? "";

        if (bStr[i].Length > bMaxStrLen)
            bMaxStrLen = bStr[i].Length;
    }

    var col1Width = Math.Max(col1Header.Length, aMaxStrLen);
    var col2Width = Math.Max(col1Header.Length, bMaxStrLen);
    var format = $"{{0,{(alignToRight ? "" : "-")}{col1Width}}} " +
        $"{{1,{(alignToRight ? "" : "-")}{col2Width}}}"; // not optimal

    Console.WriteLine(format, col1Header, col2Header);
    Console.WriteLine(format, col1Border, col2Border);

    for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(format, aStr[i], bStr[i]);
    for (var i = a.Length; i < b.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(format, null, bStr[i]);
}
```

---

Данный метод выводит 2 любых массива (спана) с нормальным отступом в "Power Shell Style".

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно проверить какой из них больше, а потом решать вопрос с выводом. Лучше для этого алгоритма сделать 1 метод, который бы принимал 2 массива и просто их выводил в столбик.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer pervogo massiva: ");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr1 = new int[a];


        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer vtorogo massiva: ");
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr2 = new int[b];

        int min = 10;
        int max = 100;
        Random rand = new Random();

        string output = "";

        if (arr1.Length > arr2.Length)
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
                if (i < arr2.Length) {
                    arr2[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
                    output += $"{i})  {arr2[i]}  {arr1[i]}\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    output += $"{i})      {arr1[i]}\n";
                }
            }
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
            {
                arr2[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
                if (i < arr1.Length)
                {
                    arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
                    output += $"{i})  {arr1[i]}  {arr2[i]}\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    output += $"{i})      {arr2[i]}\n";
                }
            }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
```

Можно например вот так:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer pervogo massiva: ");
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr1 = new int[a];


        Console.WriteLine("Vvedite razmer vtorogo massiva: ");
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr2 = new int[b];

        Random rand = new Random();

        string output = "";

        if (arr1.Length > arr2.Length)
            output = GetString(arr1, arr2);
        else
            output = GetString(arr2, arr1);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static string GetString(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {
        int min = 10, max = 100;
        Random rand = new Random();
        string output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
            if (i < arr2.Length)
            {
                arr2[i] = rand.Next(min, max);
                output += $"{i})  {arr2[i]}  {arr1[i]}\n";
            }
            else
            {
                output += $"{i})      {arr1[i]}\n";
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: А можно ли добиться такого же результата без метода?

Comment: да, это первый пример, там просто дважды используется аналогичный код